# Visualforce Search Page - SOQL Results Pagination

Tags: apex, visualforce, search, pagination

I've been building a VF search page and have run into a slight issue.  I want to add pagination so that I can return all of my results and allow users to go through the results at 20 records a page.  I have been trying to look at instructions online and can't seem to link my results with the pages.  Can anyone take a look and provide me some insight into how I could get pagination with my code?  Thanks!

Controller:

```
public with sharing class CorpGovSearchController {

   private integer counter=0;  //keeps track of the offset
   private integer list_size=20; //sets the page size or number of rows
   public integer total_size; //used to show user the total size of the list
   public Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c agmt1 {get;set;}

  // the soql without the order and limit
  private String soql {get;set;}
  // the collection of agreements to display
  public List<Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c> agmts {get;set;}

  // the current sort direction. defaults to asc
  public String sortDir {
    get  { if (sortDir == null) {  sortDir = 'asc'; } return sortDir;  }
    set;
  }

  // the current field to sort by. defaults to last name
  public String sortField {
    get  { if (sortField == null) {sortField = 'Name'; } return sortField;  }
    set;
  }

  // format the soql for display on the visualforce page
  public String debugSoql {
    get { return soql + ' order by ' + sortField + ' ' + sortDir + ' LIMIT 100';}
    set;
  }

  // init the controller and display some sample data when the page loads
  public CorpGovSearchController() {
    soql = 'select Name, Nike_SF_Contract_Category__c, Apttus__Agreement_Category__c, NikeSF_Sub_Geography__c, NikeSF_Geography__c, ID, Apttus__Status_Category__c, Apttus__Status__c, NikeSF_Agreement_Type__c from Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c where name != null';

    runQuery();
  }

  // toggles the sorting of query from asc<-->desc
  public void toggleSort() {
    // simply toggle the direction
    sortDir = sortDir.equals('asc') ? 'desc' : 'asc';
    // run the query again
    runQuery();
  }

  // runs the actual query
  public void runQuery() {

    try {
      agmts = Database.query(soql  + ' order by ' + sortField + ' ' + sortDir + ' LIMIT 100');
      total_size= agmts.size();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      ApexPages.addMessage(new ApexPages.Message(ApexPages.Severity.ERROR, 'Ooops!'));
    }

  }

     public void reset() {
       agmt1.NikeSF_Sub_Geography__c='';
    }
  // runs the search with parameters passed via Javascript
  public PageReference runSearch() {

    String Name = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Name');
    String agmtPurpose = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('agmtPurpose');
    String agmtCategory = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('agmtCategory');
    String subgeography = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('subgeography');
    String geography = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('geography');
    String ID = Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('ID');

    soql = 'select Name, Nike_SF_Contract_Category__c, Apttus__Agreement_Category__c, NikeSF_Sub_Geography__c, NikeSF_Geography__c, ID, Apttus__Status_Category__c, Apttus__Status__c, NikeSF_Agreement_Type__c from Apttus__APTS_Agreement__c where name != null';
    if (!Name.equals(''))
    soql += ' and Name LIKE \'%'+String.escapeSingleQuotes(Name)+'%\'';
    if (!agmtCategory.equals(''))
        soql += ' and Nike_SF_Contract_Category__c LIKE \''+agmtPurpose+'\'';  
    if (!agmtCategory.equals(''))
      soql += ' and Apttus__Agreement_Category__c LIKE \''+agmtCategory+'\'';
    if (!geography.equals(''))
      soql += ' and NikeSF_Geography__c LIKE \'' + ''+geography+'\'';
    if (!subgeography.equals(''))
      soql += ' and NikeSF_Sub_Geography__c LIKE \''+subgeography+'\'';  


    // run the query again
    runQuery();

    return null;
  }

   public PageReference Beginning() { //user clicked beginning
      counter = 0;
      return null;
   }

   public PageReference Previous() { //user clicked previous button
      counter -= list_size;
      return null;
   }

   public PageReference Next() { //user clicked next button
      counter += list_size;
      return null;
   }

   public PageReference End() { //user clicked end
      counter = total_size - math.mod(total_size, list_size);
      return null;
   }

   public Boolean getDisablePrevious() { 
      //this will disable the previous and beginning buttons
      if (counter>0) return false; else return true;
   }

   public Boolean getDisableNext() { //this will disable the next and end buttons
      if (counter + list_size < total_size) return false; else return true;
   }

   public Integer getTotal_size() {
      return total_size;
   }

   public Integer getPageNumber() {
      return counter/list_size + 1;
   }

   public Integer getTotalPages() {
      if (math.mod(total_size, list_size) > 0) {
         return total_size/list_size + 1;
      } else {
         return (total_size/list_size);
      }
   }



}
```

VF Page:

```
<apex:page controller="CorpGovSearchController" sidebar="false">

  <apex:form >
  <apex:pageMessages id="errors" />

  <apex:pageBlock title="Agreement Search" mode="edit">

  <table width="100%" border="0">
  <tr>  
    <td width="200" valign="top">

      <apex:pageBlock title="Filters" mode="edit" id="criteria">

      <script type="text/javascript">
      var oldG;
      var oldAP;
      function doSearch() {

        if(document.getElementById("{!$Component.geography}").value=='' || document.getElementById("{!$Component.subgeography}").value=='__' || document.getElementById("{!$Component.geography}").value!=oldG){
           document.getElementById("{!$Component.subgeography}").value='';          
           }

        if(document.getElementById("{!$Component.agmtPurpose}").value=='' || document.getElementById("{!$Component.agmtCategory}").value=='__' || document.getElementById("{!$Component.agmtPurpose}").value!=oldAP){
           document.getElementById("{!$Component.agmtCategory}").value='';           
           }

        oldG = document.getElementById("{!$Component.geography}").value;
        oldAP = document.getElementById("{!$Component.agmtPurpose}").value;
        searchServer(
                document.getElementById("Name").value,
                document.getElementById("{!$Component.agmtPurpose}").value,
                document.getElementById("{!$Component.agmtCategory}").value,
                document.getElementById("{!$Component.geography}").value,
                document.getElementById("{!$Component.subgeography}").value          
                );        
      }

      </script> 

      <apex:actionFunction name="searchServer" action="{!runSearch}" rerender="results,debug,errors">
          <apex:param name="Name" value="" />
          <apex:param name="agmtPurpose" value="" />
          <apex:param name="agmtCategory" value="" />
          <apex:param name="geography" value="" />
          <apex:param name="subgeography" value="" />          
      </apex:actionFunction>



      <table cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2">
      <tr>
        <td style="font-weight:bold;">Agreement Name<br/>
        <input type="text" id="Name" onkeyup="doSearch();"/>
        </td>
      </tr>        
       <tr>
           <td style="font-weight:bold;">Agreement Purpose<br/>  
            <apex:inputfield id="agmtPurpose" value="{!agmt1.Nike_SF_Contract_Category__c}"  onchange="doSearch();"/> 
           </td>
      </tr>   
      <tr>
        <td style="font-weight:bold;">Agreement Category<br/>  
        <apex:inputfield id="agmtCategory" value="{!agmt1.Apttus__Agreement_Category__c}"  onchange="doSearch();"/> 
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="font-weight:bold;">Geography<br/>
          <apex:inputfield id="geography" value="{!agmt1.NikeSF_Geography__c}"  onchange="doSearch();"/>  
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td style="font-weight:bold;">Sub-Geography<br/>
          <apex:inputfield id="subgeography" value="{!agmt1.NikeSF_Sub_Geography__c}"  onchange="doSearch();"/>  
        </td>
      </tr>

      </table>

      </apex:pageBlock>

    </td>
    <td valign="top">

    <apex:pageBlock mode="edit" id="results">
        <apex:pageBlockButtons location="both" >
           <apex:outputPanel id="myButtons">
                <apex:commandButton action="{!Beginning}" title="Beginning" value="<<" disabled="{!disablePrevious}" reRender="myPanel,myButtons"/>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!Previous}" title="Previous" value="<Previous" disabled="{!disablePrevious}" reRender="myPanel,myButtons"/>        
                <apex:commandButton action="{!Next}" title="Next" value="Next>" disabled="{!disableNext}" reRender="myPanel,myButtons"/>
                <apex:commandButton action="{!End}" title="End" value=">>" disabled="{!disableNext}" reRender="myPanel,myButtons"/>        
            </apex:outputPanel>
       </apex:pageBlockButtons>

       <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!agmts}" var="agmt">

            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">
                    <apex:commandLink value="Agreement Name" action="{!toggleSort}" rerender="results,debug">
                        <apex:param name="sortField" value="Name" assignTo="{!sortField}"/>
                    </apex:commandLink>
                </apex:facet>
                <apex:outputLink value="/{!agmt.id}">{!agmt.Name}</apex:outputLink>
            </apex:column>

            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">
                    <apex:commandLink value="Agreement Category" action="{!toggleSort}" rerender="results,debug">
                        <apex:param name="sortField" value="Apttus__Agreement_Category__c" assignTo="{!sortField}"/>
                    </apex:commandLink>
                </apex:facet>
                <apex:outputField value="{!agmt.Apttus__Agreement_Category__c}"/>
            </apex:column>

            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">
                    <apex:commandLink value="Agreement Type" action="{!toggleSort}" rerender="results,debug">
                        <apex:param name="sortField" value="NikeSF_Agreement_Type__c" assignTo="{!sortField}"/>
                    </apex:commandLink>
                </apex:facet>
                <apex:outputField value="{!agmt.NikeSF_Agreement_Type__c}"/>
            </apex:column>

            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">
                    <apex:commandLink value="Status Category" action="{!toggleSort}" rerender="results,debug">
                        <apex:param name="sortField" value="Apttus__Status_Category__c" assignTo="{!sortField}"/>
                    </apex:commandLink>
                </apex:facet>
                <apex:outputField value="{!agmt.Apttus__Status_Category__c}"/>
            </apex:column>

            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">
                    <apex:commandLink value="Status" action="{!toggleSort}" rerender="results,debug">
                        <apex:param name="sortField" value="Apttus__Status__c" assignTo="{!sortField}"/>
                    </apex:commandLink>
                </apex:facet>
                <apex:outputField value="{!agmt.Apttus__Status__c}"/>
            </apex:column>

            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">
                    <apex:commandLink value="Geographies" action="{!toggleSort}" rerender="results,debug">
                        <apex:param name="sortField" value="NikeSF_Geography__c" assignTo="{!sortField}"/>
                    </apex:commandLink>
                </apex:facet>
                <apex:outputField value="{!agmt.NikeSF_Geography__c}"/>
            </apex:column>

            <apex:column >
                <apex:facet name="header">
                    <apex:commandLink value="Sub-Geography" action="{!toggleSort}" rerender="results,debug">
                        <apex:param name="sortField" value="NikeSF_Sub_Geography__c" assignTo="{!sortField}"/>
                    </apex:commandLink>
                </apex:facet>
                <apex:outputField value="{!agmt.NikeSF_Sub_Geography__c}"/>
            </apex:column>

        </apex:pageBlockTable>
    </apex:pageBlock>
    </td>
  </tr>
  </table>

  <apex:pageBlock title="Debug - SOQL" id="debug">
      <apex:outputText value="{!debugSoql}" />           
  </apex:pageBlock>    

  </apex:pageBlock>

  </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

Comment: It will be ok for you to use a JS library such as datatable?, I found this page amazing https://force201.wordpress.com/2014/03/15/connecting-datatables-to-json-generated-by-apex/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Abandoned

Answer (score 2):

I would highly suggest that you look at the Salesforce `StandardSetController` class. It handles pagination out of the box for you and is very easy to use. There are a few 'gotchas' with support for some standard objects, but it looks as though you are using a custom object.

To construct a new `StandardSetController` in your page controller you just need to use `Database.getQueryLocator(String s)` to convert your SOQL string into a query locator. You can then leverage all the pagination methods provided.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/apexcode/apex_pages_standardsetcontroller.htm

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're keeping track of the offset with the `counter` variable, but I don't see you actually using the `OFFSET` keyword in your [SOQL pagination query](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_offset.htm).

Also, you might want to add a check in the `Previous()` method to verify that the counter is never set to less than 0.